# fetch returns undefined error in Web notification Push

Tags: php, jquery, web, notifications, fetch

I am currently studying web notification and I stumbled in [this guide](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-02/01-subscribing-a-user/?fbclid=IwAR26pL1ixEJtvbN7hPHjZvr5b_QrPDxqHRd2WHbYKN7OSwPGuD-RbM_ZJIY). Currently everything's good but I seems to have an error in `fetch()` as it returns an undefined response error.

```js
function sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(subscription) {
  return fetch('send_notification.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Bad Status code from server');
    }
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(responseData) {
    if (!(responseData.data && responseData.data.success)) {
      throw new Error('Bad response from server.');
    }
  });
}
```

send_notification.php

```
<?php
  echo json_encode(array("response"=>"ok"));
?>
```

This is how it looks like when it's passed:

[image: send_notification]

[image]

I don't know why I'm getting no response from my `send_notification`. This is my whole file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/nbxe6ks3sjntjj0/push_notification2.zip/file

---------EDIT-----------
and this is what I meant about the undefined response.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `response` object has no `ok` property. `ok` is the *string value* of the `response` property, therefore your logic should be:

```
if (response.response != 'ok') {
  // your logic...
}
```

You're going to have the same issue with `response.json()`, however there's no logical guess I can make for what you're expecting that to be given the output in the images you've shown.

Comment: hi, i updated my question. and as you can see, I dont think that that was the issue. I just thought that the 'response' was like the return value of my send_notification, but anyway as the picture stated the "response" after my fetch seems to have an error. @Roy

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it is working without any problem. `console.log(response)` is returning 200 OK.